# Rails forward to parent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have two models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :created_at, :name, :status, :company_id
  has_many :phases, :dependent => :destroy

end


class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :created_at, :date_due, :name, :project_id, :status
  belongs_to :project

end
```

When a new phase is created, I would like to forward the user to the show project page for the project that the new phase belongs to.

I've tried this, as well as a few variations, but am not quite sure of the best way to write it:

```
def create
    @phase = Phase.new(params[:phase])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @phase.save
        redirect_to @phase.project
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @phase.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**

Rake Routes:

```
          phases GET    /phases(.:format)                  phases#index
                 POST   /phases(.:format)                  phases#create
       new_phase GET    /phases/new(.:format)              phases#new
      edit_phase GET    /phases/:id/edit(.:format)         phases#edit
           phase GET    /phases/:id(.:format)              phases#show
                 PUT    /phases/:id(.:format)              phases#update
                 DELETE /phases/:id(.:format)              phases#destroy
        projects GET    /projects(.:format)                projects#index
                 POST   /projects(.:format)                projects#create
     new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)            projects#new
    edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)       projects#edit
         project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)            projects#show
                 PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)            projects#update
                 DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)            projects#destroy
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Updated Controller - now working. Needed to remove the respond_to block (could probably just include the different format options around the redirect, as well)

```
  def create
    @phase = Phase.new(params[:phase])

    if @phase.save
      redirect_to project_url(@phase.project)
    else
      render action: "new"
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
redirect_to project_path(@phase.project)
```

Note: This will only work if you have your routes set up correctly.

See the [Using redirect_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to) section in Rails Guides for more information.

**Edit:**

The problem is probably that we aren't passing an `id` to `project_path(:id)`.

```
redirect_to project_path(@phase.project.id)
```

Comment: I tried that, It sends me to "http://localhost:3000/phases". I'm adding my routes to my question.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `redirect_to :controller=>'projects', :action => 'show', :id => @phase.project`?

Comment: Try declaring your routes like this first: `resources :projects` and the same for phases. See this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

Comment: No luck. It seems very straightforward. I must be missing something buried deeper.

Comment: Ah! You were right with your first answer, the problem was with my controller's respond_to block. Posting an update above to show my final code.